# Deploying WebServices with JBoss 7

Tags: web-services, jboss7.x

I'm trying to deploy WebServices with JBoss 7. I have a single class with @WebServices annotated. However, I keep getting the error from JBoss...

Caused by: org.jboss.as.server.deployment.DeploymentUnitProcessingException: JBAS011232: Only one JAX-RS Application Class allowed.  com.sun.jersey.api.core.ScanningResourceConfig com.sun.jersey.api.core.DefaultResourceConfig com.sun.jersey.api.core.ClasspathResourceConfig com.sun.jersey.api.core.ApplicationAdapter com.sun.jersey.api.core.ResourceConfig com.sun.jersey.api.core.servlet.WebAppResourceConfig com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.DeferredResourceConfig com.sun.jersey.api.core.ClassNamesResourceConfig com.sun.jersey.api.core.PackagesResourceConfig

Where is this mysterious other application?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like maybe you bundled Jersey in your application. JBoss AS7 uses RESTEasy for it's JAX-RS implementation.

Comment: Your right. I accdiently told IntelliJ to bundle Jersey in the WAR.